# Google Sheets date conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have dates in column D in Google Sheets.  I want the cells to highlight red if 30 days have passed and there is not a comment date in column F.

*Example:*

Column D:  Submittal Date  6/29/2019
Column F:  Comments Received (date)

If I don't receive comments within 30 days of submittal date the cell should turn red to alert me to follow up.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF((NOT(D1>TODAY()-30)) * (F1="") * (D1<>""), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wonderful - thank you very much the quick response - it works like a charm!

Comment: @JoanneGabriel you are free to not accept the answer if it helped you solve your issue